# Wordpress File permission issue all of a sudden

Tags: wordpress, permissions

My website had been working well. But recently I started to see some abnormalities.

When I upload a media file, it says the file can't be moved to upload/2022/08; When I create a new post, the featured image choice section on the backend are gone; On frontend, plugin WP-SCSS is reporting file permission issue on the cache folder;

I had to manually change the related folder from 0755 to 0777 to solve these issues. But why all of a sudden it requires 0777 while it never had? The only change I made recently to the server is doing some package upgrade for my linux server. It was a one-click-go and I didn't take a closer look to what had been upgraded but I do remember seeing most items are related to PHP8.0 or PHP8.1. Could this be the reason the file permission issue is acting up?

Comment: Probably the ownership of these folder is changed in a some way... could you see if the site folder have all the same uid and gid?

Comment: You also have to pay attention to apache or nginx... probably they run with a different user than before...

Comment: I checked folder owner they are all the same. I compared the results of `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` with another server which has no issue, they are identical.